How to solve modified Helmholtz integral involving time derivative?
For the modified Helmholtz operator $ (\nabla^2 - p^2)$, where $p$ is a constant then how to solve for $f(x,t)$ when the system is spherically symmetric. The equation for $f(x,t)$ and position vector x is dependent on time $t$ is given as-
$$ (\nabla^2 - p^2) f(x,t) = \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial t^2}\phi (x,t) $$
where the $x$ is the 3-dimensional spatial vector, and mod represents the magnitude. Now to the best of my knowledge the integral for $f(x,t)$ by using Green's function method will take the form of RHS as
$$f(x,t) = \int d^3 x' \frac{e^{-p |x-x'|}}{ |x-x'|} \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial t^2}\phi (x',t) $$
I couldn't figure out how to handle the time derivative term. The terms in $\phi$ after the time derivatives it will give $x_i v^i$ kind of terms. So how to solve it for $f(x,t)$. I need full solution for general $\phi$, so for simplicity we can consider $\phi(x,t) = \frac{e^{-p|x'|}}{|x'|}$

Start by writing the Laplacian in spherical coordinates.

@Aruralreader so the dependence of $|x'|$ will be in terms of $r$ and because of spherical symmetry $\theta$ and $\phi$ will not appear. Now the problem appears when there is a velocity term present multiplying with Green's function term, how to integrate it then?
